# Convert pandas series strings to numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, series

`Following series, contains result as string of lists with values either PASS or FAIL.
Input:-

| result |
| --- |
| "['PASS','FAIL']" |
| "['PASS','FAIL','PASS','FAIL']" |
| "['FAIL','FAIL']" |

Output:

| result |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 0 |

If any row has at-least one PASS as value then return 1 else return 0
Input:-

| result |
| --- |
| "['PASS','FAIL']" |
| "['PASS','FAIL','PASS','FAIL']" |
| "['FAIL','FAIL']" |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are lists use `in` statement:

```
df['result'] = [int('PASS' in x) for x in df['result']]
#alternative solution
df['result'] = df['result'].apply(lambda x: 'PASS' in x).astype(int)
```

If strings use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df['result'] = df['result'].str.contains('PASS').astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple and fast approach, use a regex with [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
# if your want a robust check
df['result'] = df['result'].str.contains(r'\bPASS\b').astype(int)

# or if you're sure there are only PASS/FAIL
df['result'] = df['result'].str.contains('PASS').astype(int)
```